# Using the Googlemaps Geocoder and Storing the Data

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am building an Events site in which the address of a given event will be stored to be used within a map on the page.  Whilst viewing an Individual Events' page i would like to provide a list of similar events on side of the page.  I would also like to rank this list by distance and display a small map with a marker on it for each item on the list.

I was thinking of Geocoding the Events address upon content input and then storing this data within the sites database.  Doing this would allow me to calculate the distance of an event on the server and then provide an ordered list to display.

My question is this:
Would this violate the Googlemaps Terms of Service?

These terms:

*"the geocoder for any purpose other than obtaining locations that will be displayed using the Google Maps APIs is a violation of the Terms of Service. You may use the HTTP geocoder to geocode addresses outside of your Google Maps API application so that they may be cached and later displayed using one of the Google Maps APIs, but locations obtained using the Geocoding Web Service may not be used by any other application, distributed by other means, or resold."*

Suggest that storing the data is not a problem but i am unsure that the process of ordering the list by long lat would not result in a violation.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the map your refer to in your question is a Google Map and you are using the geocoded data to display features on a Google Map, you are fine. The client-side `google.maps.Geocoder`[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) is intended for dynamic requests that are based on real-time user interaction that drives a need to perform on-the-fly geocoding. But Google encourages you to consider using the `Geocoding Web Service`[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) on the server-side, when you wish to pre-geocode static addresses or coordinates prior to using the response values on a Google Map. Storing those values is assumed.

It is common to perform some form of post-response/post-storage processing on those values, just like the ordering by distance that you describe, to fit whatever use case is needed to populate your map with the appropriate data. I understand you want to be careful to remain within the TOS, but what you describe sounds pretty standard.